# Uso correcto del FutureBuilder cuando ya se ha llamado al Future previamente

Tags: flutter, dart, asincronismo

Tengo un proyecto en el que llamo un **Future**(`initProducts()`) que obtiene una lista para un `Provider` al comienzo de la aplicación (al momento de crear el `Provider` en el `Main`). Esta lista posteriormente la utilizo reiteradas veces en mi proyecto en diferentes páginas, por lo que tengo que comprobar que el **Future** ya se haya completado.

¿Cada vez que compruebo si ya se ha completado el Future debo hacerlo con un `FutureBuilder` aunque el Future ya se haya llamado anteriormente o simplemente debo utilizar un `if` y que el `NotifyListeners()` redibuje posteriormente el Widget?

Aquí lo demuestro para que se entienda mejor:

Donde llamo `initProducts()`:

```
void main() async{
  runApp(    
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ProductProvider()..initProducts()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

initProducts() en sí (comprueba que no se haya completado ya anteriormente):

```
  Future<List<Product>> initProducts()async{
    if(_products.isEmpty){
      _products = await ProductsDatabaseService.readProducts() ?? []; //se rellena la lista que necesito posteriormente
      notifyListeners();
    }
    return _products;
  }
```

Cuando uso posteriormente los datos obtenidos con initProducts(), ¿Cuál de estas es la forma correcta?

**Forma 1:**

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: productProvider.initProducts(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          //código que se realiza si ya se ha completado el Future
        }else{
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
```

**Forma 2:**

```
if(productProvider.products.isNotEmpty){
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount:productProvider.products.length,
      itemBuilder://Widget que devolverá en base a la lista obtenida por el Future
    );
}else{
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

Comment: en la segunda forma tienes algún widget que esté escuchando el provider?

Comment: Sí, es el builder de un widget que escucha el provider.

Comment: lo mismo usas para la forma 1? tienes algún widget escuchando al provider?

Comment: Si, también. De lo contrario no funcionaría. No se si se entiende pero ambas formas funcionan correctamente, yo estoy buscando la más optima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma 2 es la más óptima, si ya usas algún gestor de estados y tienes tu bloc/notifier/provider que indica que debe repintar (`notifyListeners`), y también tienes un widget que escucha cambios, ya no es necesario el uso del `FutureBuilder`, está de más.

Con eso evitas no solo un widget menos en el árbol, sino que también, llamadas innecesarias a `productProvider.initProducts()` para realizar la validación, ahorras ciclos de CPU(casi no se siente).